# Show that if $a\equiv b \pmod m$, then $\gcd(a,m)=\gcd(b,m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, gcd-and-lcm

I still don't have a clear approach, but this is what I see.

$m \mid b$ and $m \mid a$ or $m\nmid b$ and $m\nmid a$.

I may think that the way is showing $\gcd(a,m)\leq\gcd(b,m)$ and $\gcd(a,m)\geq\gcd(b,m)$

Comment: Let $b=an+k$, where $n,k$ are integers. Then, it is almost equivalent to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838918/unable-to-understand-why-gcdbtr-b-gcdb-r). Please see my answer there.

Comment: "Let $gcd(b,r)=g$, and$ b=gm$ and$ r=gn$. Then, m and n are coprime". Why is that true?

Comment: Because that is the meaning of $\gcd$. $g$ is the greatest common factor, so $m$ and $n$ must not have any common factor.

Comment: right if we assume to the contrary that they have a common factor then $m=pt$ and $n=pl$ which implies $b=(g*n)t$ and $n=(gp)l$ contradicting g as the gcd. Thanks man, you have helped me a lot. How old are u?. You look so young because of your picture.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $d = gcd(a,m)\to d\mid a, d\mid m\to d\mid (a-b)\to d\mid ((b-a)+a) = b$.Thus $d \mid gcd(b,m)$.Similarly $gcd(b,m) \mid gcd(a,m)$.Thus they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: using [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) $ka+tm = gcd(a,m)$ (1)

using $a\equiv b\pmod m$, $a = cm+b$

substitute into (1), $k(cm+b)+tb = (kc+t)m+tb = gcd(a,m)$

By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359806/why-is-it-true-that-if-axby-d-then-gcda-b-divides-d): $gcd(b,m) | gcd(a,m) $

In a same way, $gcd(a,m) | gcd(b,m)$

=>$gcd(a,m)  = gcd(b,m)$